# Docker sometimes cannot see jar file

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have a weird problem, that sometimes a docker container cannot see a `.jar` file, while most of the time it does not have any problem with it.

Before i show you the docker image, a little bit of background. Normally i build a jar archive before running my container, a pretty simple container to run a spring boot application. However at some seemingly random point in the daily routine it does not boot up with the container reporting "Unable to access jarfile".

I thought it must be some weird permission stuff, so i took snapshot of my "target" directory when working and when it stopped working via `ls -alR target` and later comparing those snapshot with `git diff`. It does not show any difference. I am still pretty convinced it must be related to file-permissions, locking or something of that sort but i do not know where to start.

**A little edit with more information here:**
The problem is that `ls` in the docker container showing 0 files, while ls on the host machine lists all files regularly. The docker container info shows the mount correctly, if i copy the path and print its contents via `ls` it shows those files on the host. So unfortunately it seems to be a problem in Docker bind. I have read that this could happen because if inodes with single file mounts (see https://medium.com/@jonsbun/why-need-to-be-careful-when-mounting-single-files-into-a-docker-container-4f929340834). Recreating the container, with the same mount solves the problem.

I am on Mac 12.0.1 btw. Any ideas appreciated.

The docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8-oraclelinux8
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD "java" "-jar" "app.war"
```

And `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - sql1
    volumes:
      - ./target:/app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - "sql1:sqlserver"
    ...
```

Comment: Please send your files tree

Comment: Too large and does not make a difference. In theory i could delete the whole filetree and use the jar only for running.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but I don't see your Dockerfile as robust enough to produce consistent results regardless of the state of your localhost workspace. I may ask, are you building your war file manually and then creating your Docker container?

Please try to follow this approach if it fits your needs :

1. make sure you delete jar/war files before building the container.
2. Have a multistage Dockerfile with a "build" phase for your spring boot app where you generate the jar/war file from a builder image (ant, gradle, maven), and then have a second stage where the jar/war file gets copied over to it's final location and the application gets executed, this way you ensure consistency and that the file will be there at all times :

This is an example for my spring boot templates that I use very often, it's quite generic (as I handle the renaming of the jar file without having to worry about how pom.xml is configured individually) and I guess could be implemented in a variety of scenarios

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-18 as builder

WORKDIR /usr/app/
COPY . /usr/app
RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip
RUN JAR_FILE="target/*.jar"; cp ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar

FROM openjdk:18
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY --from=builder /app.jar /usr/app
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

docker compose :

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - sql1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - spring-boot-api-network
    volumes:
      - ./target:/app
...
```

NOTE : I would also remove the "links" option as it is a [legacy feature you should avoid using](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) and use networks instead :

You can try this network implementation added at the bottom of your compose file, just make sure you don't forget to add the `network:` to the sql1 portion as well

```
networks:
  spring-boot-api-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: 182.16.0.1/24
            gateway: 182.16.0.1
    name: spring-boot-api-network
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. It is actually not supposed to be independent from host machine - maybe i am missing some docker key concepts here but rebuilding the image for every debug build is not what i desire. Thus the shared volume with the host machine in my configuration. I think it is valid. 
And yes probably the problem of docker not being able to access the jar would not be there if it would be build into the container. But that is not the point here.